# I am facing issue while uploading app bundle and it showing me error and rejecting the build

Tags: paypal, cloud, google-play-console

We found an issue in the following area(s):

Version code 52: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Location Data Type - Precise Location, Possible SDKs: com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk, com.paypal.sdk:paypal-partner-android-sdk
Version code 52: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Personal Info Data Type - Phone number
To bring your app into compliance, follow these steps:

com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk: Consider upgrading to a policy-compliant version of the SDK if available from your SDK provider, or removing the SDK.
com.paypal.sdk:paypal-partner-android-sdk com.paypal.sdk:paypal-partner-android-sdk: Consider upgrading to a policy-compliant version of the SDK if available from your SDK provider, or removing the SDK.
About the Data safety section in Google Play User Data policy

i tried to add new implent in build.gradle files and try to give permissing in .xml